# How to generate a random real symmetric square matrix with uniformly distributed entries

Tags: matlab, random, matrix, symmetric

I would like to generate a random real symmetric square matrix with entries uniformly distributed between 0 and 1.
My attempt is:
`a = rand(5);
    b = a + a.'`

My worry is that whilst matrix a is uniformly distributed according to the documentation http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/techdoc/ref/rand.html matrix b might not be since the average of two random numbers might not be the same as the original number.

I tried to use
    `hist(a);
    hist(b)`
but not sure how to interpret the resulting graph.
EDIT: According to Oli matrix b is no longer uniformly distributed, is there a way to make it that way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, if you do that then `b` will not be uniformly distributed; it will have a [triangular distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution#Distribution_of_mean_of_two_standard_uniform_variables).

How about something like this:

```
a = rand(5);
b = triu(a) + triu(a,1)';
```

where [`triu()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/triu.html) takes the upper-triangular part of the matrix.

Comment: thanks, Oli, any advice on how to make it uniformly distributed?

Comment: thanks, Oli, so using triu function keeps the uniform distribution? I have just run it and hist(b) looks different to what I had for my matrix b.

Comment: @Aina: This approach avoids adding any elements together.

Comment: @Aina: 25 elements is not enough to produce a useful histogram.  You should generate, say, 10000 of these random matrices, and then do a histogram on the whole thing.

Comment: thanks, Oli, just tried to create a 1000x1000 matrix and then compared its histogram to the histogram of matrix b created using your method. Looks exactly the same! Thanks, again!

Answer (score 2):

You can only get uniformly distributed entries on half of the matrix.

```
a=rand(5);
b=triu(a).'+triu(a,1);
```

Comment: thanks g24l, so then it is IMPOSSIBLE to have a random symmetric matrix with uniformly distributed entries?

Comment: @Aina : I was talking on how to generate the matrix. The elements of the matrix are uniformly distributed, but not random, and not iid.